# uiautomator dump does not dump when using multi display

Tags: android, adb, ui-automation, android-uiautomator, android-11

I am running "uiautomator dump" on custom Android device running on Multi-display mode with Android 11 OS.

It does not dump the screen. it does not even create window_sump.xml file on /sdcard path.

However it works on single display mode.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s `dump` with [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend you can get the content of both displays (*providing that the focus is on the secondary display, otherwise only the main display is dumped, so you have to interact with the second activity before getting the dump*).

For example, using emulator with a secondary display and Phone and Clock running, json format to be able to use `jq` and filtering unique package names, you get

```
dump -ah | jq '.. | .package? | select(. != null)' | sort -u
⚠️  CulebraTester2 server should have been started and localport 9987 redirected to remote port 9987.
"com.android.systemui"
"com.google.android.deskclock"
"com.google.android.dialer"
```

This is filtering the package names but you can take a look at the full dump by yourself.

[image]

Not ideal, but works.